# How to connect ORACLE DB, error The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

How to connect ORACLE DB in virtual machine windows 7 with IntelliJ IDEA.I have jdbc7.jar in the libraries and I try that way. Shows me this error :

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error input-output: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
... 17 more
```

and

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    String serverName = "000.000.000.000";
    String portNumber = "1521";
    String sid = "abcd";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
    String username = "user";
    String password = "pass";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Comment: Is the server name really "000.000.000.000"? That looks like a very strange host name and also not like a valid IP address.

Comment: This is only example ip...i have other ip which gave success -> cmd: ping (ip virtual machine)

Comment: ping is something different. Try `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1521`

Comment: You might need "//". Try with "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+ serverName +":"+ portNumber +"/"+ serviceName

Comment: @igr same mistake

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  telnet Not connected

Comment: Then it could be the firewall which blocks the traffic

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i turn off friewall It did not change anything